# MySQL syntax error, for no apparent reason

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, phpbb

I have this MySQL statement writen in PHP, but it seems to contain a syntax-error.

```
$user_forum_sql = ( !empty($forum_id) ) ? " WHERE session_page = " . intval($forum_id) : '';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $session_table_name . '"'.$user_forum_sql.'"';
```

This is the error I'm having. I'm not sure what is causing it.

```
SQL Error : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '""' at line 1

SELECT * FROM ""
```

Comment: I see you're putting all the WHERE session_page... in `"`, `echo $sql` to see how it looks. try it like this:  `$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $session_table_name.' '.$user_forum_sql;`

Comment: gives me an error in syntax

Comment: `echo $sql` to see how the query looks like, I was just trying to guess, as I see on your link `$session_table_name` is empty too

Comment: still gives me an error 
the job of this is supposed to be "The index page also scans the users plus session tables for active users. When online users reaches close to a thousand this check becomes costly in time. This isn't even a hack, I ended up having an external script on a cron job to run the exact query on a per minute basis. Result is stored in a hash table, and phpBB then queries the hash table for the list of on-line users."

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ""` is not a valid SQL statement, you are missing a table name there

Comment: it will surely give you an error, you're not sending the table name to mysql. check why `$session_table_name` is empty and remove the `"` from around `$user_forum_sql;` as I said in my first comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $session_table_name.' '.$user_forum_sql;`

Comment: how do i check why $session_table_name is empty?
am i supposed to put my actual table name there which would be phpbb_sessions

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_forum_sql = ( !empty($forum_id) ) ? " WHERE session_page = " . intval($forum_id) .'' ;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $session_table_name.$user_forum_sql;
echo $sql;
```

Your $session_table_name is empty, so you might have not started your session or have not set the value.

Comment: I think you need to remove : '' from $user_forum_sql.Also if you can please echo $sql

Comment: also im  pretty sure removing user_forum_sql will just break the command

Comment: this is what should happen me having an external script on a cron job to run the exact query on a per minute basis. Result is stored in a hash table, and phpBB then queries the hash table for the list of on-line users.

Comment: when i put your edit in phpmyadmin and try to show it it still gives me an sql error

Comment: also would it be better for me to just upgrade to discourse?